# Different results between raw MongoDB and Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I run this query directly in my MongoDB:

```
db.events.aggregate([
  {$match: {name: 'new_session', created_at: {
    $gte: ISODate('2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
    $lt: ISODate('2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z')
  }}},
  {"$project": {
  "user_id": "$user_id",
  "year": {"$year": "$created_at"}, 
  "month": {"$month": "$created_at"},
  "day": {"$dayOfMonth": "$created_at"}
}},
{"$group": {
     "_id": {"year": "$year", "month": "$month", "day": "$day"},
     "uniques": {"$addToSet": "$user_id"},
     "total_sessions": {"$sum": 1}
}}
])
```

It returns what I expect.

Running the next query with Mongoid model returns different results:

```
results = Event.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match" => {"name" => 'new_session', "created_at" => {
    "$gte" => @start_time,
    "$lt" => @end_time
  }}},
  {"$project" => {
    "user_id" => "$user_id",
    "year" => {"$year" => "$created_at"}, 
    "month" => {"$month" => "$created_at"},
    "day" => {"$dayOfMonth" => "$created_at"}
  }},
  {"$group" => {
       "_id" => {"year" => "$year", "month" => "$month", "day" => "$day"},
       "uniques" => {"$addToSet" => "$user_id"},
       "total_sessions" => {"$sum" => 1}
  }}
])
```

Any idea why the difference? is Mongoid doing some magic behind the scenes? I didn't enable caching. I've checked if its connected to the correct DB. Everything seems fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Your Mongoid query has `$dayOfMonth` which your raw query doesn't. Also, what exactly are `@start_time` and `@end_time` in Ruby?

Comment: you are right, I copied the wrong query. The results are still different (the query wasn't the problem).

@start_time:
  ``@start_time = DateTime.strptime('2011-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')``

@end_time:
  ``@end_time = Time.now``

Comment: What do `@start_time.zone` and `@end_time.zone` say? Note that the MongoDB timestamps are UTC (as are all times inside MongoDB AFAIK), is someone applying a timezone adjustment behind your back in Ruby?

Comment: The zone for ``@start_time`` is ``+00:00``, and for ``@end_time`` its ``IST``

Comment: So `@end_time`'s time-of-day component won't be 00:00:00 when it reaches MongoDB and the date component could change as well; the time-of-day won't be 00:00:00 even without the timezone issue. If you're really trying to work with dates then maybe `Date.today` would be better than `Time.now`.

Comment: @muistooshort It didn't change the results I'm getting when querying through Mongoid. `@end_time.zone` returns UTC now.

Comment: Looks like they should be doing the same things. I think you're going to have to start unrolling the pipeline to see what documents are being found by one but not the other.